# References for closed string collisions on finite number of fixed type mutually intersecting orbifolds with D-branes at the orbifold singularities

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, branes

I don't know if this topic is studied at all but I'm looking for good references for closed string collisions on a finite number of fixed type mutually intersecting football orbifolds with D-branes at the orbifold singularities where the D-branes are configured in a symmetrical way (for example the D-branes coincide with the $0$-skeleton of a cube or some other polyhedron).

Basically I want to read about firing off sequences of closed strings originating from the eight D-branes and understand the patterns on the outer boundary of the intersecting orbifolds. I can imagine the string splitting and recombinations could induce a high level of complexity but perhaps there is a reference that deals with these computations for a simple case.